# Extending DialogService in Prism

Tags: wpf, mvvm, dialog, prism

On the Prism Library website there is a few notes about Simplify your Application Dialog APIs.
https://prismlibrary.com/docs/wpf/dialog-service.html

Let's say I have a Solution with multiple projects, MainProject, Modules.Module1, CoreProject. So creating this `DialogServiceExtensions` class in my Core project.

```
public static class DialogServiceExtensions
{
    public static void ShowNotification(this IDialogService dialogService, string message, Action<IDialogResult> callBack)
    {
        dialogService.ShowDialog(nameof(NotificationDialog), new DialogParameters($"message={message}"), callBack, "notificationWindow");
    }
}
```

I also put `NotificationDialog` and `NotificationDialogViewModel` in my Core project

I can call it at any project/module, but the question is how can I tell prism that `NotificationDialog` ViewModel is `NotificationDialogViewModel`.

Where should I register the dialog, to be able to use thru the hole solution? In my MainProject App.xaml.cs like usual?

```
protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
        {
            containerRegistry.RegisterDialog<NotificationDialog, NotificationDialogViewModel>();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where should I register the dialog, to be able to use thru the hole solution? In my MainProject App.xaml.cs like usual?

If the app wants to show a dialog, you have to do this, as modules are essentially optional (they can be swapped out after deployment or they don't need to exist).

If a module wants to show a dialog (and not the app), you can decide whether it's part of your app's interface to its modules (then put the registration in the app) or not (then put it in the module, each module that uses it, that is, registrations may override each other).